# How to reset all the balances of users in an ERC-20 to 0? How to recyle an ERC-20

Tags: erc-20

Assume we have Token 1 which is an ERC-20 contract that has issued 200 tokens to User A.
Then we want to have Token 1 'recycled' into a new token, rather than create a new contract.
After the contract has been recycled, User A's 200 tokens should return to 0.
Recycled Token then issues 100 tokens to User A.

User A should only have 100 tokens.

Is this possible?

The first solution I thought of is to iterate over all the addresses and set them to 0, but this is unfeasible, clearly.

The second solution I thought of was to use a "check" function that checks which token epoch the user has tokens from, and then burn the epoch tokens are are not active. The problem is still that balanceOf would return their old, non recycled, balance until this they call into the contract. That could lead to some issues.

The clear solution is to issue a new ERC-20 token contract, but I wanted to explore if this was possible.

Comment: You might also store the epoch last time balances are updated. When it is requested you check epoch, if it did change then reset account.

Comment: @Ismael Ah this sounds like it could work. To clarify, you mean this: change the balanceOf() function to check the epoch?

Comment: I'd add the check to every use of balance that might be affected.

Comment: @Ismael My concern is that if an external contract called balanceOf() a user that hasn't had their balance updated. Because a contract could be checking if they have a balance, and if the user never did anything to have their balance reset, it would return the old epoch balance.

Comment: The proposed behavior is against the behavior of most ERC20 tokens, so it is likely contracts not aware of the particularities will break. In any case it should be possible that balanceOf checks the epoch and in case of mismatch returns the reseted value.

Comment: Do you have an upgradable ERC-20 contract or how would you change the functionality of a deployed contract in the first place?

If you have a private balance mapping and a public `balanceOf()` function as described that would work without breaking anything. From the outside it just looks like regular ERC-20.

Comment: @soliditydeveloper.com I have a token id that gets mapped to the ERC-20. That token id will expire and a new one will be made, token id 1 -> 2. The solution would be to deploy a new ERC-20 mapped to token 2. I wanted to try and recycle the token 1 erc-20 though. So if we changed the balanceOf function, would it still be erc-20 compatible as long as it returns the balance?

Comment: @primitivefinance Absolutely, as long as it's still a view function and you don't change any state inside `balanceOf`.

Comment: @soliditydeveloper.com ah so thats the problem we'd run into! basically we need to reset a user's balance to 0 each epoch, so when do we do this? How can we do this so when an epoch is active, balanceOf will return 0 even if a use hasnt called a function that would reset their balance?

Comment: @primitivefinance In `balanceOf` you just return the correct balance, in `transfer`, `transferFrom` and `approve` you can change the state.